# luci on lighttpd- 500 internal server error

Tags: lua, lighttpd, luci

I'm running LUCI with lighttpd on ubuntu 16.04.
i'm using lua5.1 and luci-0.9

the directory structure in `www/html/` is:

```
root@toor-VirtualBox:/var/www/html# ls
cgi-bin  cgi-bin-nodes.html  cgi-bin-status.html  index.html  index.lighttpd.html  luci  luci-static
```

when i run

```
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require "luci.cacheloader"
> require "luci.sgi.cgi"
> 
> luci.dispatcher.indexcache = "/tmp/luci-indexcache"
> 
> luci.sgi.cgi.run()
```

I get 500 internal server error:

```
.../luci/host//usr/lib/lua/luci/statistics/datatree.lua:28: attempt to index upvalue 'sections' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    .../luci/host//usr/lib/lua/luci/statistics/datatree.lua:28: in function '__init__'
    /home/luci/host//usr/lib/lua/luci/util.lua:70: in function 'Instance'
    .../luci/controller/luci_statistics/luci_statistics.lua:30: in function 'v'
    /home/luci/host//usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:496: in function 'createtree'
    /home/luci/host//usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:179: in function 'dispatch'
    /home/luci/host//usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:143: in function </home/luci/host//usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:142>
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/plain
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

any solution?

Comment: My guess is: the `run` method may need to be called with `:` instead of `.` and the library fails to check for that and give you a proper error.

Comment: solved by following [this post](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_a1e6528101013k0k.html).  but now I'm getting this  error with 500 internal server error:      7月 30 14:59:07 toor-VirtualBox lighttpd[20600]:         no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
7月 30 14:59:07 toor-VirtualBox lighttpd[20600]:         no file './luci.so'
7月 30 14:59:07 toor-VirtualBox lighttpd[20600]:         no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/luci.so'

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/openwrt/luci/issues/1105

Comment: it doesn't solve the issue :(